# Mongodb $lookup with pre init

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used to use populate to combine below document but I want to use $lookup instead but the resident profile_key is unhashed when I use $lookup but it shows properly when I populate

```
const resident = new Schma({
 _id: ObjectId('abcde'),
 device_key: 'asdf'
 profile_key: 'asdfasdf' //AES 256 key
})

resident.pre('init', doc => {
  let decrypt;
   decrypt = decryptProfile(doc.profile_key);
   doc.profile = decrypt;
   doc.profile_key = {}
})
```

```
device.aggregate([
  {$match: cond'},
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'resident',
    localField: 'key',
    foreignField: 'device_key
    as: 'resident'    
  }},
  {$unwind: '$residnet'}
])
```

expected result

```
const device = {
 _id: ObjectId('asdf'),
 key: 'asdf',
 resident: {
   _id: 'abcde',
   device_key: 'asdf',
   profile: {
    name: 'resident 1'
   }
 }
}
```

actual results

```
const device = {
 _id: ObjectId('asdf'),
 key: 'asdf',
 resident: {
   _id: 'abcde',
   device_key: 'asdf',
   profile_key: 'asdfasdf' //not decrpyt 
 }
}
```

populate works fine as expected results

Answer (score 0):

The `resident.pre('init', ()=>{})` hook that you wrote won't work with aggregation framework. In this case, you need to use aggregation middleware functions.
You can review mongoose documentation on [Aggregation Hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#aggregate) to help you

Comment: I don't understand when I use find or findById it returns with decrypt data. @giuan